# How to enforce a child class to set attributes using abstractproperty decorator in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, abstract-class

I want to enforce a Child class to set several attributes(instance variables), to achieve I am using abstractproperty decorator in python 2.7. Here is the sample code:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractproperty
class Parent(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @abstractproperty
    def name(self):
        pass

class Child1(Parent):
    pass

class Child2(Parent):
    name = 'test'

class Child3(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'test'

obj_child1 = Child1()
```

Child1 object creation gives an error as expected.

```
obj_child2 = Child2()
```

Child2 object creation works fine as because abstract attribute 'name' is set

However

```
 obj_child3 = Child3()
```

gives *TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Child3 with abstract methods name*

I did not understand:although the attribute 'name' is set in the **init** 
method, why the Child3 object creation is throwing type error.

My requirement is set attributes inside a method of child class. An explanation of what is wrong with child2 class and if there is a better way to enforce a child class to set attributes in a method will help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your title mean? Did you mean to say, *"I did not understand..."*?

Comment: I think the question titles make more sense now @Tagc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do some like this,
parent class:

```
class Parent(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @abstractproperty
   def name(self):
       pass
```

Child class:

```
class Child(Parent):
    name = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'test'
```

Now

`obj = Child()
obj.name`

gives the required output of 'test'.

By doing this you can enforce a class to set an attribute of parent class and in child class you can set them from a method.
It is not a perfect solution that you require, but it is close. The only problem with this solution is you will need to define all the abstractproperty of parent as `None` in child class and them set them using a method.

Answer (score 8):

A simpler solution will be

```
class Parent(object):
    name = None
    def __init__(self):
        if self.name == None:
            raise NotImplementedError('Subclasses must define bar')

class Child1(Parent):
    pass

class Child2(Parent):
    name = 'test'

class Child3(Parent):
    def __init__(self)
        self.name = 'test'
```

`obj1 = Child1()` raises NotImplementedError

`obj2 = Child2()` works fine

`obj3 = Child3()` works fine. This is what you need to enforce a child class to set attribute `name` and set the attribute from a method.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I believe is happening.

When you try to instantiate `Child1`, you have not provided an implementation for the abstract property `name`. You may have done so like this:

```
class Child1(Parent):
    @property
    def name(self):
        return "foo"
```

Since the class does not provide an implementation for all abstract methods inherited from its parents, it is effectively an abstract class itself, and therefore cannot be instantiated. Trying to instantiate it gives you your `TypeError`.

In the case of `Child2`, you define it as:

```
class Child2(Parent):
    name = 'test'
```

In this case, you're *overwriting* the `name` property of the class so that it's no longer referencing an abstract property that needs to be implemented. This means that `Child2` is not abstract and can be instantiated.

One difference I noticed was that when `name = 'test'` as you've implemented it, `vars(Child2)` returns output like this:

```
{..., '__abstractmethods__': frozenset(), ..., 'name': 'test'}
```

However, when you change this to something like `foo = 'test'`, you get this:

```
{..., '__abstractmethods__': frozenset({'name'}), ..., 'foo': 'test'}
```

Notice that the `__abstractmethods__` property is an empty set in the case that you define `name = 'test'` i.e. when `Child2` can be instantiated.

Finally, in the case of `Child3` you have to bear in mind that the abstract property is stored as a property of the *class itself*, which you don't redefine anywhere.

As soon as you try to create an instance of it, the interpreter will see that it's missing an implementation for at least one abstract method and throw the `TypeError` you see. It doesn't even *reach* the assignment `self.name = 'test'` in the constructor.

---

To answer your second part about how to *enforce* children to always provide an implementation for abstract properties/methods when they can do something like you did - I'm not actually sure if it's possible. Python is a language of consenting adults.

Comment: thanks for your observation, what I did not understand is why Child3 object creation is giving an error. Child1 and  Child2 object creation is clear to me.

Comment: @daved Edited that in just as you commented. :)

Comment: thanks for the answer, it helped me understand what is happening @Tagc